# IntelliJ IDEA Won't Load - Stuck on Splash Screen

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

I've set up my JDK_HOME, JAVA_HOME, and PATH variables to their appropriate values. I've also installed both a 64 and 32 bit JDK and JRE. When I try to load the Intelij IDEA, it freezes and doesn't show the progress bar (see screenshot). It loads after ~5 hours, but that is obviously taking too long.

[image]

Comment: Try executing the JAR from the command line.  See what stacks come out of it from there.  It'd also be helpful to include what OS you're on.

Comment: Well, that's just it - I execute IntelliJ from its JAR on Linux.  Are you on OS X or Windows?  I don't know.

Comment: I'm on Windows. What would I execute? The exe doesn't give a error message, it just freezes on the splash screen. Do you know if there's a way to get the error message (if there is one)?

Comment: All there is in the bin folder is a few .exe's and some .bat's. I think the .jar is only for linux.

Comment: That's the likely case.  I don't know much about running IntelliJ on Windows, unfortunately.

Comment: Ok. Would you have any ideas why it's just running and not giving an error message or loading?

Comment: Check the log for any errors. On Windows it should be in `{user-home}/.IdeaIC/System/logs` See if there is an error in the `idea.log` file. Make sure you have v13.1.2 released a few days ago. It fixed some hang issues. The fact you are getting the splash screen indicates that it's finding the JDK. If I recall, any JDK issues are reported pre-splash screen. You can try setting the `IDEA_JDK` and `IDEA_JDK_64` environment variables to a 32-bit and 64-bit JDK respectively (I'd go with Java 7 or 8).

Comment: There's a weird thing where it loads after ~5 hours, but then all the build/compiling takes the same time. Is there some kind of bottleneck?

Comment: I fixed this problem by rebooting, renaming the cache folder, then starting the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was actually my antivirus (avast). After fixing that, it launched in <1min.

Comment: After fixing what?

Answer (score 2):

Check the log file of IntelliJ
its located in:

```
c:\Users\{your_username_in_windows}\.IntelliJIdea13\system\log\
```

or for linux

```
/home/{User_name}/.IntelliJIdea13
~/.IntelliJIdea13
```

There you will see the error or the step that is stops at

Comment: There's nothing there.

Comment: maybe replace the XX with 13? Sorry I forgot to replace the XX for the linux paths

Comment: On Mac it's located at `~/Library/Logs/IntelliJIdea13/`

Comment: On MacOS if you installed IntelliJ with the JetBrains Toolbox, logs are located at `~/Library/Logs/JetBrains/IntelliJIdeaX` where `X` is the version number.